# Multiple images upload with serial no

Tags: php, ajax

I am using this code for multiple images upload.

I want if I upload multiple images one time and in a column it will send 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and if I upload a second time 6, 7, 8, 9 and so on.

I don't want serial order to be auto incremented because I need to change it as needed.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
$errors= array();$s=$i++;
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
    {
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152)
        {
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true)
        {
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
            {
                // Create directory if it does not exist
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false)
            {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name);
            }
            else
            {   
                 //rename the file if another one exist
                 $new_dir="user_data/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
            //mysql_query($query);          
        }
        else
        {
                print_r($errors);
        }
       // echo $file_name = $file_name.",";
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE,serial) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type','$s'); ";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
    if(empty($error))
    {
        echo "Success";
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean for the duration that this user keeps uploading images, OR, for all users that upload images EVER

Comment: Also there is a sort of standard practice that says table names and column names should be lower case. Rememeber *nix is case sensitive and if you start mixing case you will likely get errors later when you forget which column names are UPPER CASE and which are lower case

Comment: RiggsFolly its for one user only means only admin is uploading images... and after uploading he will rearrange the orders of images as per his need.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 options:

- Save the serial using javascript.
- Save the serial using $_SESSION.
- Save the serial using your database.

For example we use the $_SESSION container:

```
isset($_SESSION['img_count']) ? : $_SESSION['img_count']=0; //set the image counter for each session
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"user_data/".$file_name) ? $_SESSION['img_count'] ++ : ''; //update the counter ONLY when the file has been copied to your hard drive.
$query="INSERT into upload_data (FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE,serial) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type','$_SESSION[img_count]')"; // insert it on the database.
```

You can of course apply the same principle to a javascript so each user's computer handle's these numbers and then you just need to include them in the form you are using.